# Apps Script won't get any logs from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to run a function from Google Apps Script in a HTML page. Basically, I want to get a log message that says "Someone Clicked the Button" whenever the button is clicked. However, I click the button and still get nothing in my logs. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

function userClicked(){
  Logger.log("Someone Clicked the Button");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    
    <button id="btn">Run It</button>
    
    <script>
    
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
    
    function doStuff(){
      google.script.run.userClicked();
    }
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I have found this on an comment to an similar question >> "google.script.run is valid only inside the .HTML files found within a Google Apps Script project... You can't use that syntax from some server running on your hardware (as suggested by your index.js comment). – tehhowch Jan 6 '20 at 14:02 " so are you in a google script project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot log values using Logger in google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786526/cannot-log-values-using-logger-in-google-app-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using the new editor you can create a new deployment and then copy the url and go to another window paste and run it and you should see your button.
2. Then if you project is not a Cloud Platform Project, goto `Project Setting` and uncheck this item `Log uncaught exceptions to Cloud logs`
3. Now go to `Executions` and then move to the tab with your web app and click it and move back to the executions page and in a short time you should see a `userClicked` entree and if you open it, in the logs in the bottom of the screen.

Hopefully this will work the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    
    <button id="btn" onclick="google.script.run.userClicked()">Run It</button>
    
  </body>
</html>
```